# Can i use data-src in <img> instead of src attribut?

Tags: html, image, src

Can we use `data-src` instead of `src` attribute in `<img>` with no side effects?

we are using `data-src` only at https://www.svetandroida.cz/flightor-levne-letenky/ and everything works OK, but HTML validator say that we are missing "src" and Google News feed doesn't display our thumbnails https://news.google.com/publications/CAAqKggKIiRDQklTRlFnTWFoRUtEM04yWlhSaGJtUnliMmxrWVM1amVpZ0FQAQ?hl=cs&gl=CZ&ceid=CZ%3Acs

Do you think that missing "src" a is problem for Google not displaying our images?

Thank you

Comment: data-src is not part of any html spefication, so img-element with only this attribute and without src, does not render an image and is invalid html. Data-src is commonly used for lazy loading image by javascript-libraries to set the src-attribute after the image is actually visible to the user.

Comment: If you will do inspect element on your markup, src attribute should be there, otherwise it won't show up your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use data-src instead of src attribute in with no side effects?

No.

`data-src`, like all `data-` attributes is a mechanism to provide *custom data* for (primarily) JavaScript on a website to use.

`src` determines where to load an image from.

---

It sounds like you are using `data-src` and JS to populate `src` dynamically. While there are reasons for do this, you've seen the negative impact it has on Google and you'll have similar problems [when JavaScript fails](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Use `src`, even if it for a default you override later. (And if you are overriding it with JavaScript, consider if it would be better to override it with [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) instead).

Comment: We have <noscript> section with <img src> but not sure if Google see it. Do you think that Google is reading our sites with "scripts on" mode or something?

Comment: @AtomCZ Google bot will render the page before trying to access the images, so it will execute any javascript code before that. Hence, all sites with lazy loading images still have working images on Google.

Comment: @Esko cna you mention 1 site with the same lazyload technique so i can check it at Google Feed? Thank you